# Pull out columns of a database where the table(table(df$factorcol))==2

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

morning all. I am trying to subset my database on R - I am basically trying to make this plot on ggplot but the value I want to plot is the total number of x type of families, shaded by the no of mothers, fathers etc in it.

So I have two columns. Both are factors. Column 1 is a Rare Disease family ID, and each family ID is a factor. So to plot this out, I manually made a database from the information given back by doing the command

```
table(table(df$factorcol)==2
```

This worked as a patch job for a plot I needed but now, I can't work with it further as I need to pull out more information from the main database, essentially subset the database

I tired this code

```
x <- df$FamilyMembers[table(table(df$factocol))==2]
```

and get 124 results back which is incorrect as there can only be 104 (there are 52 families with 2 members).

I'm basically trying to recreate this plot but shade it by the no of mothers, fathers etc on ggplot which is the information on the Family Members column.

[image]

This is a picture of the code I'm using, I work inside a research environment so can't the code here and paste it. I'd really appreciate any help with this, thank you for your time and effort.

[image]

Edit: This is the output for

```
dput(head(df[c("FamilyMembers", "factorcol")], 30))
```

[image]

EDIT:Thank you for the time and effort you put into this Andy. I really appreciate it.
I basically have a column called rare disease family ID and it has 621 values. Each family has a unique ID, so I made this a factor variable as it would help group entries together. When I table(table(df$factorcol))==2, I am essentially just trying to find out how many of these are families of 2. (There are 52)
So out of these 52*2 people, I am trying to find out how many are Father, Mother and Proband. This information is stored in Participant.Tye, which is the second one. The row names are all the unique participant IDs, and I'm trying to subset this to select families of 2 and plot out what are their members.

Comment: Can you post the output of `dput(head(df[c("FamilyMembers", "factorcol")], 30))` in the question, please?

Comment: @RuiBarradas means paste the text output of `dput` so answers can try to replicate your problem and provide a solution which fits/uses your data :)

Comment: I appreciate that but I work inside a research environment and I can't copy/paste anything from there.

Comment: Sorry but the screenshots are the best way I've found so far. And I can't access internet except two whitelisted sites inside there, so its a bit tricky\

Comment: @Ar1229 please make up a test dataset then, screenshots are basically useless for anyone trying to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the answer to what I think I understand you're now looking for!

Updated solution which plots 'Number of each family member type' who live in families of two:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(viridis)
#> Loading required package: viridisLite

df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Participant.Type, ~Rare.Diseases.Family.Id,
           "Mother",              "122002132",
          "Proband",              "122002132",
           "Father",              "122006236",
           "Mother",              "122006236",
          "Proband",              "122006236",
          "Proband",              "122007201",
           "Mother",              "122007201",
           "Father",              "122007201",
           "Mother",              "111000376",
          "Proband",              "111000376",
           "Mother",              "111001381",
           "Father",              "111001381",
          "Proband",              "111001381",
           "Father",              "111001616",
          "Proband",              "111001616",
           "Mother",              "111001616",
          "Proband",              "111001638",
          "Proband",              "111001711",
           "Mother",              "111001711",
           "Father",              "111001711",
           "Father",              "111001737",
           "Mother",              "111001737",
          "Proband",              "111001737",
          "Proband",              "111901806",
           "Mother",              "111901806",
           "Mother",              "111001854",
     "Full Sibling",              "111001854",
           "Father",              "111001854",
          "Proband",              "111001854",
           "Mother",              "111001905"
  ) |> 
  mutate(across(.fns = factor))


df |> 
  group_by(Rare.Diseases.Family.Id) |> 
  add_tally() |> 
  filter(n == 2) |> 
  ggplot(aes(Participant.Type, fill = factor(Participant.Type))) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_fill_viridis("N in family", option = "magma", discrete = TRUE)
```

[image]

Some notes on what this is doing:

- `group_by`/`add_tally` are adding a column of how many family members are in each family
- `filter` is reducing to only those with two family members
- I used this to replace the `table(table(df$factorcol))==2`, which I don't think was giving what you expected. In essence this line:

  - First tallied the number of people in each family, returning a vector the length of families
  - Then tallied *the number of families of each size*, returning a vector the length of the number of unique family sizes
  - Then tested this vector for how many family size category contained exactly two families (regardless of family size)
  - So filtering by this value doesn't quite work. Hence alternative method suggested above.

Comment: newly updated solution now I think I understand your question!